# GCP Load balancer path routes between frontend and backend not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have a backend service which is a REST Api .NET backend project and a frontend Angular project.
I want to use Google Cloud Load Balancer to:

- route requests that match: **mydomain.com/api** to the REST API backend app
- route requests that match **mydomain.com/client** to the angular app.

I have created the endpoint groups and backend services for both these apps and put both of them inside the load balancer.

I have configured the load balancer routing rules as following:

```
defaultService: projects/my-proj/global/backendServices/api-backend-service
name: path-matcher-1
pathRules:
- paths:
  - /api/*
  service: projects/my-proj/global/backendServices/api-backend-service
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
- paths:
  - /client/*
  service: projects/my-proj/global/backendServices/client-backend-service
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
```

However the first route works as expected but not the second one.
As I can see the second one loads the page meaning the page title is displayed and page is blank, but isn't able to load the css and javascript content since it is not rewriting url's to those requests.

Comment: Have you referred to this google links [Redirect examples](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#redirect_examples) and [Configure URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#gcloud), which will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, but none of those has any answers to the problem because its a url rewrite and not e redirect

Comment: If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: No solution found yet

Comment: Have you figured that out?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Nginx [ingress](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) with URL rewrite OR if your deployed  app has endpoint exists like /api and /client, you can use a classic load balancer with Standalone NEGs (no gke ingress), documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#how_to)